# Dynamic data not recorded by LOADRUNNER or JMeter

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

In one of my project we are searching for a vehicle number, it has to show the vehicle number exists or not.but i in the devtool i an not able to find the searched vehicle number.

Let's say I have searched for 5555 , 5555 should record as a parameter in JMeter load runner, even developper tools also it's not showing.

How can I handle this in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you start a transaction just before you submit your form with '5555' in it within the recording of loadrunner (either default sockets recorder or fiddler-based proxy recorder).   You submit your form.  You stop your transaction.  You then complete your recording.

What do those requests between the start and end transaction markers look like?

Answer (score 0):

If [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) don't show the request it means that there is no request, most probably it happens on the client side only hence there is nothing to test with JMeter/Loadrunner there.

Or it might be hidden/filtered/using another protocol.For example [this page](https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester) won't show sent and received requests at the default view because they're happening in a single [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) connection and you need to switch to `WS` tab and then open `Messages` view:

[image]

The above website cannot be recorded with JMeter/Loadrunner, in JMeter you will need to use [WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) and in Loadrunner [`web_webcoket_*` functions](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2022-2022-r1/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/examples/lrFuncRef_WVF_web_websocket_Example.htm)

You can also consider using a more powerful packet capturing solution like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which can catch literally everything and look for your payload in the raw network packets. It will allow you to identify the network protocol.

And last but not the list: try recording your scenario in ["porno mode"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) as it might be the case your application has cached the response and it's being returned from i.e. [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) so no actual network request is being made